# Start up shell stuck in /bin/sh how to change it back to zsh default at startup

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, kali-linux, sh

Whenever I start my cli, it keeps starting up in /bin/sh.

I've searched various different forms and none so far have worked for my issue. I also tried various options like chsh (1) <--- this only works for the session.
chsh -s /bin/bash $username   <--- says "you may not change the shell for user"

All options so far are just temp and I have not access to root user as well.

Comment: Speak to your administrator

Answer (score 1):

`chsh` is the proper method, but if you don't have root access, you cannot change your login shell permanently this way. Ask the person who has root access to do so.

If this is not possible, you can use a workaround - put the command `exec zsh` in your `.profile` file. When `/bin/sh` starts as a login shell, it will execute contents of this file, and this command will tell it to replace itself with `zsh`.